# Flask + Docker app - The container dies when i run docker run

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have an application with Dockerfile + docker-compose.

Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml

I have a CI, which creates an image from my dockerfile and send it to the hub.docker

Travis.yaml

When I drop this image on my `cloud` server I can not run this image by running the command below:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 flask-example
```

because the container dies.

Besides the downloaded image from hub.docker after compiled by travis, will I need docker-compose on my server? Executing the command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

To run the application? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Run `docker run -it flask-example` to see what error.

Comment: Check the logs with [`docker logs container`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).

Comment: @Sraw thanks for reply. but this only enters the interactive mode of the python image that is inside dockerfile, I still can not solve.

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant details such as the actual Dockerfile and the `docker-compose.yml` in the question itself, not as external links.  It doesn't necessarily need to be the whole thing; a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual issue is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running docker with `-d` flag detached your container, which mean that it runs in background.
Thus, you cannot see the error. Just remove this flag and you will see why it is dying.

From the link to your `docker-compose` file, it seems that port 80 is already in used (by `frontend` container) so maybe you can try using a different port?
(for example: `docker run -d -p 8080:80 flask-example`)

Second, you are right. 
`docker-compose` is just another way to run your container. You don't have to use both.

Comment: Thanks you reply.

The container dies with the command you mentioned, it's as if it does not look at docker-compose.yaml

Comment: @MarcusMann did it answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

I could not turn, container dies. I think he is not identifying what was built.

The docker run command does not perform what was built inside docker-compose.yml

As a test would you be able to run on your local computer?

Comment: You are mixing other problems together. Why are you using docker-compose for building? i think it's a bad practice. simply build with `docker build -f Dockerfile -t flask-example .` and use the `flask-example` within `docker-compose.yml` with `image` tag instead of `build` tag.